# DBUtils - using ResultSetHandler

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to use ResultSetHandler to pass List of students to a servlet but getting below error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
```

the method in Student class is

```
          public List<Student> list2() throws SQLException {
          Connection connection = null;
          List<Student> studentList = null;
           try {
            Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)
              envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
             connection = ds.getConnection();

             ResultSetHandler h = new ArrayListHandler();

              QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner(ds);

              String sql = "select student_id, student_name from tbl_student";

              studentList = (List<Student>)run.query(sql, h);


          }catch(SQLException sqle) {
              sqle.printStackTrace();
          }

          catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          finally {
              DbUtils.closeQuietly(connection);
          }

          return studentList;
      }
```

the alternative method where i am not using DButils is working fine .

```
      public List<Student> list() throws SQLException {
            Connection connection = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

            try {
              Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
              Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
              DataSource ds = (DataSource)
                envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
               connection = ds.getConnection();
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select student_id, student_name from tbl_student");
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.setId(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                    student.setName(resultSet.getString("student_name"));
                    studentList.add(student);
                }
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
                if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
                if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            }

            return studentList;
        }
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you add the complete stack trace?

Comment: when you execute the same query `select student_id, student_name from tbl_student` from a dbclient what does it return ? does it return the value 'id' in the student_id column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you to use the BeanListHandler to fetch all rows from the ResultSet and turn them into a List of JavaBeans as shown below:

```
QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner(dataSource);
ResultSetHandler<List<Student>> resultSetHandler = new BeanListHandler<Student>(Student.class);
List<Student> studentList = queryRunner.query("SELECT student_id, student_name FROM tbl_student", resultSetHandler);
```

Comment: what's the difference between using BeanHandler and  ArrayListHandler?

Comment: The `BeanListHandler` creates an instance of the given class and puts the values of given columns into matching properties. Hence you have to rename your columns to match the names of your bean properties. The SQL should be: `SELECT student_id id, student_name name FROM tbl_student`,

Answer (score 0):

if column name is not match Bean's property, please use columntoPropertyOverrrides, this will be perfect to resolve this problem.

```
 public <T> List<T> queryBeanList(String sql, final Class<T> clazz,final Map<String, String> columnToPropertyOverrides) throws SQLException { 
    ResultSetHandler<List<T>> rsh = new ResultSetHandler<List<T>>(){ 
        @Override
        public List<T> handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException { 
            BeanProcessor bp = new BeanProcessor(columnToPropertyOverrides); 
            return bp.toBeanList(rs, clazz);
        }

    };
    return query(sql, rsh);
 }
```